# calabash-android - error installing APK - remote Read-only file system

Tags: android, jenkins, android-emulator, jenkins-plugins, calabash-android

I am trying to run calabash-android tests on my Android APK, on one machine with one emulator the tests run fine, however on another machine with the same code but a different emulator I get an error.

Here are the commands I run in a .sh file:

```
rm -rf screenshot*
rm -rf test_servers
bundle exec calabash-android build "jenkins.apk"
bundle exec calabash-android run "jenkins.apk" -p android -v
```

And here is the error log:

> 2017-04-28 14:03:36 - Installing:
>   test_servers/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk 2017-04-28
>   14:03:36 - [ 10%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 21%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 32%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 43%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 53%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 64%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 75%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 86%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [ 96%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk [100%]
>   /data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk adb: error:
>   failed to copy
>   'test_servers/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk' to
>   '/data/local/tmp/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk': remote
>   Read-only file system
>   test_servers/0124c485b6b2589f08b4f8d4e6c01c05_0.9.0.apk: 0 files
>   pushed. 11.6 MB/s (609369 bytes in 0.050s) 2017-04-28 14:03:40 - java
>   -jar "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/calabash-android-0.9.0/lib/calabash-android/lib/screenshotTaker.jar"
>   emulator-5744 "screenshot_0.png" 2017-04-28 14:03:41 - It looks like
>   your app is no longer running.  It could be because of a crash or
>   because your test script shut it down. 2017-04-28 14:03:41 - Server
>   not responding. Moving on. Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as
>   failure

Can anyone explain why the apk won't install on this emulator, why does it have a "Remote Read-Only file system?

EDIT: I have tried adding the following:

```
adb remount
```

But I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

and let me know what that does?
[Credit](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/151167/read-only-file-system-on-emulator)

Comment: Can you try 'adb root' and then 'chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard' after the mount command and see what that does